# Interactive Pre-Commit Hook in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, githooks

I'm working on an interactive pre-commit Git Hook to ensure that a certain set of criteria have been met prior to the commit (eg. updating particular files in the repo). I've been basing my checklist off of the example [here](https://vickylai.com/verbose/interactive-pre-commit-hook-checklist/). My hook has identical implementation but has different question text. Currently, it works perfectly in Git Bash.

However, for a team-wide implementation I need to have it working within IntelliJ, as most developers use Git functionality within the IDE. Using the example hook linked above, my commits fail with the error:

`0 files committed, 1 file failed to commit: COMMIT TEST MESSAGE Would you like to play a game? .git/hooks/pre-commit: line 6: /dev/tty: No such device or address`

I would like to have the complete interaction contained within IntelliJ, if possible. If this is not possible, I would begin looking into IntelliJ plugin development in order to implement this within organizational restrictions.

For convenience, the Git hook linked above is pasted below.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Would you like to play a game?"

# Read user input, assign stdin to keyboard
exec < /dev/tty

while read -p "Have you double checked that only relevant files were added? (Y/n) " yn; do
case $yn in
    [Yy] ) break;;
    [Nn] ) echo "Please ensure the right files were added!"; exit 1;;
    * ) echo "Please answer y (yes) or n (no):" && continue;
esac
done
while read -p "Has the documentation been updated? (Y/n) " yn; do
case $yn in
    [Yy] ) break;;
    [Nn] ) echo "Please add or update the docs!"; exit 1;;
    * ) echo "Please answer y (yes) or n (no):" && continue;
esac
done
while read -p "Do you know which issue or PR numbers to reference? (Y/n) " yn; do
case $yn in
    [Yy] ) break;;
    [Nn] ) echo "Better go check those tracking numbers!"; exit 1;;
    * ) echo "Please answer y (yes) or n (no):" && continue;
    esac
done

exec <&-
```

Comment: Have you figured out a solution for this?

Comment: No, this was 2 years ago and I accepted the response explaining why it's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, IDE is not a terminal, and does not provide any tty you can use interactively. You need either to make you hook show a GUI prompt, or implement what you want in a different way.

There are plugins already implementing pre-commit hooks, e.g. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9278-pre-commit-hook-plugin

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks for confirming my suspicions. Theothetically, could I implement a script that opened a terminal that would then run the aforementioned script? My business requirement is that it initializes in IntelliJ, but doesn't need to reside completely (or terminate) within the application